# How to fix this? NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I want to create an icon. I wrote that code and i have this problem. Is there anything missing from the code below?

```
from tkinter import *

root.Tk()
root.title("Hello World")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Ciss/Desktop/Mine/Python/www.ico")

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ciss\Desktop\Mine\Python\py.py", line 9, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

Comment: Maybe try change `root.Tk()` with `root = Tk()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you didn't define `root`

what is `root` in `root.Tk()`?

You can do something like this,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Hello World")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Ciss/Desktop/Mine/Python/www.ico")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yeah, sorry buddy. I don't drink enough water. Thank you

Comment: It's okay! Don't forget to accept the answer for reminding you about the water 